# How could I store lambda functions inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: javascript, python, lambda, conditional-operator

[Someone](https://editor.p5js.org/cbrwn/sketches/xKE8rHPL) shared their code and I saw a bunch of functions that were stored in what seemed to me to be a dictionary and. So, I liked the idea and I *borrowed* them. The code that the person wrote it in was in JS, and I work with Python, so I translated the code into Python.

Here is what that person wrote in JS:

```
EasingFunctions = {
  // no easing, no acceleration
  linear: t => t,
  // accelerating from zero velocity
  easeInQuad: t => t * t,
  // decelerating to zero velocity
  easeOutQuad: t => t * (2 - t),
  // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  easeInOutQuad: t => t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t,
  // accelerating from zero velocity 
  easeInCubic: t => t * t * t,
  // decelerating to zero velocity 
  easeOutCubic: t => (--t) * t * t + 1,
  // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration 
  easeInOutCubic: t => t < .5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1,
  // accelerating from zero velocity 
  easeInQuart: t => t * t * t * t,
  // decelerating to zero velocity 
  easeOutQuart: t => 1 - (--t) * t * t * t,
  // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  easeInOutQuart: t => t < .5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t,
  // accelerating from zero velocity
  easeInQuint: t => t * t * t * t * t,
  // decelerating to zero velocity
  easeOutQuint: t => 1 + (--t) * t * t * t * t,
  // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration 
  easeInOutQuint: t => t < .5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t
}
```

And it works fine if you ran this code. However in the code I translated, it gave me an error saying that I miss a paranthesis, comma, or a colon. Here is the code:

```
EasingFunctions = {
  # no easing, no acceleration
  linear: lambda t : t,
  # accelerating from zero velocity
  easeInQuad: lambda t : t ** 2,
  # decelerating to zero velocity
  easeOutQuad: lambda t : t * (2-t),
  # acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  easeInOutQuad: (lambda t : t = (2*(t**2)) if t < 0.5 else ((-1+(4-2*t)) * t)),
  # accelerating from zero velocity 
  easeInCubic: lambda t : t * t * t,
  # decelerating to zero velocity 
  easeOutCubic: lambda t : (t-1) * t * t + 1, 
  # acceleration until halfway, then deceleration 
  easeInOutCubic: lambda t : t = 4*t*t*t if t < 0.5 else (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1,
  # accelerating from zero velocity 
  easeInQuart: lambda t : t ** 4,
  # decelerating to zero velocity 
  easeOutQuart: lambda t : 1 - (t-1) * t * t * t,
  # acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  easeInOutQuart: lambda t : t = 8 * t * t * t * t if t < 0.5 else 1 - 8 * (t) * t * t * t
  # accelerating from zero velocity
  easeInQuint: lambda t : t ** 5,
  # decelerating to zero velocity
  easeOutQuint: lambda t : 1 + (t-1) * t * t * t * t,
  # acceleration until halfway, then deceleration 
  easeInOutQuint: lambda t : t = 16 * t * t * t * t * t if t < 0.5 else 1 + 16 * (t-1) * t * t * t * t  
}
```

And what confused me is that the error was indicated to be the first key value that had an `if` statement in it. I thought that this was allowed in Python, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: I barely know Python, but shouldn't what comes after the `:` in a lambda be an *expression* (?) (value), not an assignment? Pasting the code into the textarea shows me errors on the `t = (2*(t**2))...` line and `t = 4*t*t*t...` line, and other similar lines

Comment: Are the keys in your dictionary predefined? If not, you should use them as strings, e.g. `'easeInQuad'`. The definition of lambda functions and using them as values is fine with Python.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `--` operator either, and `blah` doesn't mean `'blah'` as a dict literal key the way it does in Javascript object literals.

Comment: Python lambdas are for expressions only - that's stuff on the right side of equal signs. You can't have full statements, and that means no variable assignments. **Bad**: `lambda t : t = (2*(t**2)) if t < 0.5 else ((-1+(4-2*t)) * t))`, **Good**: `lambda t : (2*(t**2)) if t < 0.5 else ((-1+(4-2*t)) * t))`

Comment: @szamani20 But I want to use these functions. How could I pass arguments to them? I  guess I am going to need to find another alternative to store all of these functions in a data type or something.

Comment: @BoredComedy I posted an answer that shows exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments that you still can't figure out how to do it using string keys for dictionary, I'm posting this answer. Though, it was partially mentioned in the comments how to do this.

```
a = {
    'linear': lambda t: t,
    'easeInQuad': lambda t: t ** 2,
    'easeOutQuad': lambda t: t * (2-t),
    'easeOutQuint': lambda t: 1 + (t - 1) * t * t * t * t,
}

print(a['linear'](69))
print(a['easeInQuad'](69))
print(a['easeOutQuad'](69))
print(a['easeOutQuint'](69))
```

Result:

```
69
4761
-4623
1541364229
```

Again, as mentioned in comments, Python doesn't support `--` operation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well yeah I changed that ```--``` part. Kinda embarrassing I must say. So basically you used a string as a function's name since you passed an argument to a string, which I absolutely no idea you could do that?

Comment: I included the result. In terms of programming and code, even for people with +10 years of programming experience, there are some syntax cases that even they don't know such thing is a valid syntax. So the best way for you, is to try the code, rather than guessing.